# How to add Javascript dependencies and CSS files in Laravel correctly

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7 to build one of my application. I have the following Javascript dependencies.

1. Bootstrap
2. Data Tables
3. jQuery
4. Select 2
5. Toastr
6. D3

Now I am using the new `laravel/ui` package and has scaffolded a Bootstrap based application. It uses Laravel Mix and has compiled `app.css` and `app.js` file. The `app.js` has the following code:

`require('./bootstrap');`

The bootstrap file has following code :

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

I think in this file we need to add the other dependencies. In the documentation also it says to add the Javascript dependencies to here. I have a confusion on how to add `DataTables` and other above mentioned dependencies to the file. Which package names I need to use in the `require` ?

Also, most of these packages has their own CSS files too. How can I add the CSS files for all the dependencies in file like the `bootstrap.js` ? Currently all the CSS files are imported in the app layout blade template. If someone can add a tutorial link , that also will be great.

Comment: Well if you see inside `package.json` there are all dependencies that are included in `bootstrap.js` file. So you can install dependencies like `Datatable or select2 etc...` using npm and then you can include it in `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 2):

for install JavaScript Package on your laravel project you cad do this, 
example Datatable :

1. Install npm package

   npm install --save datatables.net-bs4
2. include it in Include it in `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

require('datatables.net-bs4');

3. Include in `resources/sass/app.scss`

@import '~datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css';

4. Run `npm run dev` in your terminal to compile the necessary files

last create a js file and include it on your `bootstrap.js` file and use package

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('table').DataTable();
});
 </script>
```

dont forget check your webpack.mix.js file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and include your compile js and css file in your template

```
  <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

i hope to help you and
sorry for bad my English

Comment: Perfect. This is what I need exactly. Now if you can suggest me how can I include page wise JS also to mix, that would be great. I need to initialize the data table only in listing page and not in loading page. How can I do this effectively ?

Comment: @HappyCoder Thanks, i don't know about that, but u can look at on https://www.sitepoint.com/use-laravel-mix-non-laravel-projects/ and https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/tree/master/docs maybe you can find your solutions about your question

Comment: Actually it was for Laravel project only. I have some Javascript in the view files like Ajax requests for loading some dropdowns and all. What I am doing now is adding these files specifically in mix configurations, and using the `<script>` to include it in the page. Thanks a lot !!